# Check if folder exists with IMAP

Tags: php, imap

I have a script which processes emails and moves them to another folder. It works fine at the moment, but I want to be able to test if the folder I want to move the emails to exists first before I execute `imap_mail_move()`. Is there a quick way of doing this?

```
$hostname="{".$imap_details['imap_server']."}INBOX".$imap_details['imap_path'];
$imap = imap_open($hostname, $imap_details['email'], $imap_details['imap_password']);
$processed_folder="INBOX/Processed";
//*** I would like to check if the above folder exists here ****
//And then do some processing here
//And then move the email to the processed folder
imap_mail_move($imap,$i,$processed_folder);
```

Comment: Do you have access to the status command? This can tell you whether a folder exists. However it may disappear between the time you check and when you do it. You'll still need to handle possible errors.

Comment: @Max, thanks, what's the status command and how do I know if I have access to it?

Comment: Is there an imap_status function?

Comment: Or you can run imap_list and cache the list of folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
$folder = 'INBOX/Processed';
$cstr = '{server.foo.com:993/ssl}';
$imap = imap_open($cstr, ...);
$list = imap_list($imap, $cstr, "*");

if( array_search($cstr.$folder, $list) === false ) {
  die("no folder!");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php

Answer (score 0):

array_search() returns the key of element in array.

if( array_search($cstr.$folder, $list) === "-1" ) {

```
 die("no folder!");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to use `array_search` (as in other answers) instead of `in_array`.

```
$folder = 'INBOX/Processed';
$cstr = '{server.foo.com:993/ssl}';
$imap = imap_open($cstr, ...);
$list = imap_list($imap, $cstr, "*");

if (in_array($cstr . $folder, $list))
  exit("No such folder!");
```